# Simulation: Find a waiting queue order that minimizes the total waiting time - Java

Tags: java, combinatorics, queue, statistics, simulation

**Intro**

Suppose we are given a queue of waiting times \$\langle t_1, \ldots, t_n\rangle\$. The first "person" \$(t_1)\$ leaves the queue immediately. The persons \$(t_i), i > 1\$ all have to wait \$(t_1)\$ units of time, which contributes \$(n - 1) t_1\$ to the total waiting time. For the \$t_2\$, it contributes \$(n - 2) t_2\$ to the total waiting time. In general, \$t_i\$ contributes \$(n - i) t_i\$. In total, we have
$$
T(t_1,\ldots,t_n) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1} (n - i)t_i
$$
units of time to wait.

Now, we wish to find the order that minimizes the total waiting time. In other words, we wish to find a permutation \$\sigma \colon \{1,\ldots,n\} \to \{1,\ldots,n\}\$ such that
$$
T(t_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,t_{\sigma(n)})
$$
is minimal.

**Code**

**`com.github.coderodde.simulation.waitingqueue.WaitingQueueSimulation.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.simulation.waitingqueue;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

public class WaitingQueueSimulation {
    
    public static final class Person {
        private final String name;
        private final double waitingTime;
        
        Person(String name, double waitingTime) {
            this.name = 
                    Objects.requireNonNull(name, "The name is null.");
            
            this.waitingTime = checkWaitingTime(waitingTime);
        }
        
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        
        public double getWaitingTime() {
            return waitingTime;
        }
        
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return name.hashCode();
        }
        
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            return ((Person) o).name.equals(name);
        }
        
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "[" + name + ", " + waitingTime + "]";
        }
    }
    
    private final Set<Person> personSet = new HashSet<>();
    
    public void add(String name, double waitingTime) {
        personSet.add(new Person(name, waitingTime));
    }
    
    public List<Person> findMinimizingOrder() {
        List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>(personSet);
        PermutationIterable<Person> iterable = 
                new PermutationIterable<>(personList);
        
        double minimumTotalWaitTime = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        List<Person> minimumTotalWaitTimeOrder = 
                new ArrayList<>(personList.size());
        
        for (List<Person> persons : iterable) {
            double tentativeTotalWaitTime = totalWaitTime(persons);
            
            if (minimumTotalWaitTime > tentativeTotalWaitTime) {
                minimumTotalWaitTime = tentativeTotalWaitTime;
                minimumTotalWaitTimeOrder.clear();
                minimumTotalWaitTimeOrder.addAll(persons);
            }
        }
        
        return minimumTotalWaitTimeOrder;
    }
    
    private static double totalWaitTime(List<Person> personList) {
        double totalWaitTime = 0.0;
        
        for (int i = 1; i < personList.size(); i++) {
            totalWaitTime += partialTotalWaitTime(personList, i);
        }
        
        return totalWaitTime;
    }
    
    private static double partialTotalWaitTime(List<Person> personList, int startIndex) {
        return personList.get(startIndex - 1).getWaitingTime() * 
              (personList.size() - startIndex);
    }

    private static double checkWaitingTime(double waitingTime) {
        if (waitingTime <= 0.0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Too small waiting time: " + waitingTime);
        }
        
        if (Double.isNaN(waitingTime)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Waiting time is NaN.");
        }
        
        if (Double.isInfinite(waitingTime)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Waiting time infinite in absolute value: " + waitingTime);
        }
        
        return waitingTime;
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.simulation.waitingqueue.Demo.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.simulation.waitingqueue;

import com.github.coderodde.simulation.waitingqueue.WaitingQueueSimulation.Person;
import java.util.List;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WaitingQueueSimulation wqs = new WaitingQueueSimulation();
        
        wqs.add("Alice", 2.0);
        wqs.add("Bob", 3.0);
        wqs.add("Jack", 1.0);
        
        List<Person> persons = wqs.findMinimizingOrder();
        System.out.println(persons);
    }
}
```

(The entire repository lives [here](https://github.com/coderodde/WaitingQueueSimulation.java).)

**Outro**

The simulation suggests that the minimizing order \$\sigma\$ is the one that is increasing in \$t_i\$: \$t_{\sigma(1)} \leq \ldots \leq t_{\sigma(n)}\$.

**Critique request**

As always, I would like to hear whatever comes to mind.

Comment: Wouldn't sorted array be a solution? Its kinda intuitive that if `t_i` > `t_j`where `i < j` then swapping them will decrease total waiting time, thus monotonically increasing order will give minimal waiting time

Comment: It is intuitive, yet I had to verify that intuition via brute force.